# how to get tow images for same job Gitlab-CI

Tags: node.js, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i want to setup gitlab-ci for `maven` project which also needs to build using `npm`

i have a job like below

```
deploy:jdk8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'npm install '
    - 'mvn compile -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
    - 'mvn package -B -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dskip.web.build=true'
  only:
    - master
  # Archive up the built documentation site.
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
```

in the below job i need both `mvn` and npm instance but i can only declare only one image/ job how can i do this ??

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you slit up the jobs and use [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#introduction-to-job-artifacts) to pass build results tot run images for testing etc.

Comment: can you please let me know with an example?